# Android / Java waiting for handler before returning inside of Service

Tags: java, android, service, concurrency, handler

I need to use an existing API that assumes that it will be used in a simple application directly in an Activity.  My use case needs to call the API from within a Service and wait for the required Handler to return the needed data.

I have tried many of the Java Concurrency options without success.  Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Below is a drastically simplified example that is more pseudo-code than a working example.

```
public class dataConnection {

Controlx xControl;
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
Context c = null;

private String data1;

Handler mHandler = new Handler() { 
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        setReturnData(msg);
        doneSignal.countDown();
    }
};

public dataConnection(Context ctx) { 
    this.c = ctx;
    xControl = new Controlx (c, mHandler);
}       

private void setReturnData(int rc) {
    this.rc = rc;
}

private int getReturnData() {
    return this.rc;
}

public int getRealData() {

    //API will timeout in 10 seconds if data is not retrieved before that
        xControl.dataCmd(10);

    //Wait here for handler to finish and then retrieve data to return
    doneSignal.await(); 

    int i = getReturnData();

    Log.v("log_tag", "RETURN NOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Handler` is using the same thread as the `getRealData()` method you're going to prevent it from ever seeing the `Message`. The `Looper` must finish one thing before it can handle anything new.

If you create a new thread and looper for the handler it'll allow both of them to function seperately. Depending on your needs a `Future<Integer>` object may be of use as well.

[Looper | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)

[Future | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Comment: Can the Handler be created and then spawned in a child thread?  I have tried the other way around by creating a thread inside of getRealData, which worked to one extent, but I could not find a reasonable way to retrieve the data (even using an AsyncTask .get method) before the getRealData returns.

Comment: Yup, the looper page gives an example class that will do just that. Passing the information back can be a bit trickier though. A few options are to set a static variable or reference that is synchronized and `doneSignal.away()` checks periodically, or letting `getRealData()` return a void and then using either the main handler or a returned `intent` to continue working on the main thread afterward. Without specifying what doneSignal.away() does exactly there could be a lot of different ways to implement it.